# MaterializeCss Use dblclick event to open datepicker modal

Tags: javascript, datepicker, materialize

I'm working with materializecss and my boss asked me to change the trigger on the datepicker modal from the classic 'click' to a double click.

Problem is, there's no documentation about that, and maybe is hard-coded in the object.

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two input elements and hide either of them. Below I've created **input1** as a datepicker and **input2** as a standard text input. Then I've hidden the first one and assigned an event listener (ondblclick) for the second one.

It may not be the best solution but works.

```js
var datepicker = document.querySelector('#input1')
var input2 = document.querySelector('#input2')

var options = {
  autoClose : true,
  container : document.body,
  onSelect : function (day) {
    input2.value = day.toDateString(), 
    M.updateTextFields()
  }
}
var instance = M.Datepicker.init(datepicker, options)

input2.ondblclick = function () {
  instance.open()
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s5 hide">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" id="input1">
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="input-field col s5">
    <input type="text" id="input2">
    <label for="input2">Pick a date</label>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: That's actually very clever. Thanks a lot